# iOS7 tab bar custom icon height - height reduces until icon gets invisible

Tags: ios7, customization, uitabbar, uitabbaritem

I implemented tab bar with custom icon sizes to match the design:
[image: initially shown image height is ok]

The first and the last icon sizes are reduced to fit below the circle line by setting the bar item sizes as follows:
[image: settings for reduction of icon height]

The strange behaviour that happens only on iOS7+ is that when the user taps already active resized tab bar icon for the second time - it gets reduced in size:
[image: after taping on active (reduced in size) icon]

And if I tap on it again - it's size is so small that it appears invisible:
[image: icon is not visible any more]

This doesn't happen on iOS5 or iOS6.

Is there something that I'm doing wrong here or any right method for reducing tab bar icon size?

Comment: possible duplicate of [iOS Tab Bar icons keep getting larger](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23306963/ios-tab-bar-icons-keep-getting-larger)

Answer (score 0):

Hi may be this is will useful for you.Give the dimension of **your tab bar items 30x30 pixels** and **@2x is 60x60**.This is working fine for me. **Image inset** give the all (0,0,0,0).