# Tab Bar Buttons become big

Tags: ios, xcode, autolayout, tabbar, uitabbaritem

I have a problem with Tab bar buttons.

As you can see in the picture below, it looks normal in the storyboard.
[image: Tabbar_storyboard]

However, when I run the simulator and click one of the tab bar buttons, they become big like this:
[image: Tabbar_simulator]

Why does it happen? and How can I fix it?

Comment: make sure cliptobounds is true for these icons

Comment: Something similar to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23306963/6541007)?

Comment: @OOPer Yes! It was similar to that problem, thank you!

Comment: @Fay007 Thank you! It wasn't checked