# IOS:UITabbar item click again and again it is reducing the UITabbar button item size in IOS 7

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I'm took the Tabbar viewcontroller in this ,I added the 5 item and .I given the image insects is (24,0,0,6).
All button images are added in xib [under the Bar item -->image]Please help.
Thanks.

Comment: i have answered a similar question here. seems like the same issue -- [iOS Tab Bar icons keep getting larger](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23306963/ios-tab-bar-icons-keep-getting-larger) ... **basically due to unbalanced image insets**

Comment: Please see this link::http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22452582/ios7-tab-bar-custom-icon-height-height-reduces-until-icon-gets-invisible.My problem also same help me please.

Answer (score 9):

<sub>Adding to a similar answer here:
[iOS Tab Bar icons keep getting larger](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23333297/2857130)</sub>

Not sure if this is an iOS7 bug but I've noticed that image insets need to be balanced.

You have specified insets for top and right but:

1. if you set a top inset, in order to balance it, you need to set the negative of it to the bottom inset
2. if you set a right inset, in order to balance it,  you need to set the negative of it to the left inset

So, instead of having image insets like `(24,0,0,6)`, use balanced image insets such as `UIEdgeInsetsMake(24,-6,-24,6)`

Doing so should protect your `tabBarItem` image from getting whacked on every tap.

---

If this doesn't suit your requirements, then redesign your `tabBarItem` image so you can have balance insets or... no insets at all.

Comment: If i put the same sizes, which you given ,the tabbar item is large and it's going to out of screen.If you din't mind just see this link::http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22452582/ios7-tab-bar-custom-icon-height-height-reduces-until-icon-gets-invisible.me also facing the same problem.Thanks

Comment: @user3840618 : Basically you want to push the image from the top and right but with imbalanced image insets, you're gonna go wrong everytime. Anyways... What are the image dimensions? I think you'd be better off if you edit the image and align it properly in an image editor and then, and only then, use it in your app.

Comment: what's the point of doing this. By doing this, you won't change anything so it's better to leave it with 0,0,0,0

Comment: This bug fixed at iOS11

Comment: I am still seeing this on iOS 11.

Comment: @de. I came up with a workaround that gets the job done.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the workaround for a bug I've encountered with `UITabBarController`'s `UITabBar`. If I tap a `UITabBarItem` once after it's selected, the icon shrinks. What I'd like to do is disable touches. `UITabBarItem` only has a setting for `isEnabled`, which grays it out if I set it to `false`...not what I was looking for.

I used a derivative of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34054914/4475605) to figure it out. With a `UITabBarController` with 3 tabs, printing `tabBarController.subviews`, I saw 3 `UITabBarButtons` and a `UIBarBackground`. The origin of UIBarBackground's frame was always `(0, 0)`, putting it at the front of the sorted array, so I really don't need to know what the subview is, just "where it is" and whether it will always be there. The `UIBarBackground` is always going to be at the front of an array of `tabBarController.subviews` sorted by `frame.minX`, so I just need to remove it from the front.

## Solution

Here's what the extension looks like:

```
extension UITabBarController {
    var buttonViews: [UIView] {
        var tabBarButtons = tabBar.subviews.sorted(by: {$0.frame.minX < $1.frame.minX})
        tabBarButtons.removeFirst()
        return tabBarButtons
    }
}
```

I also created a `struct` in my Constants file, so I don't have to remember tab names:

```
struct TabBarItem {
    static let firstTab = 0
    static let secondTab = 1
    static let thirdTab = 2
}
```

...and finally, where to use it:

In `viewDidAppear` (NOT `viewDidLoad`), add the following line to disable the `UITabBarItem` that you don't want to disable, but not gray out:

```
tabBarController?.buttonViews[TabBarItem.firstTab].isUserInteractionEnabled = false
```

In `viewWillDisappear`, re-enable the tab, as follows:

```
tabBarController?.buttonViews[TabBarItem.firstTab].isUserInteractionEnabled = true
```

Comment: +1. Ended up using your solution as I needed the image to have a larger size and balancing the image insets wasn't giving the desired results