# How to animate tab bar's items

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller

In my Swift app I have this class that handles a `UITabBar`.

```
class CustomTabBar: UITabBar {
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
    }
}
```

How can I animate the items when the user tap their?
I mean a `CGAffine(scaleX: 1.1, y: 1.1)`
So how I can animate the tab bar's items?

Comment: take a look at https://github.com/eggswift/ESTabBarController this should help

Answer (score 10, accepted):

#### First:

create a custom `UITabBarController` as follows:

```
import UIKit

enum TabbarItemTag: Int {
    case firstViewController = 101
    case secondViewConroller = 102
}

class CustomTabBarController: UITabBarController {
    var firstTabbarItemImageView: UIImageView!
    var secondTabbarItemImageView: UIImageView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let firstItemView = tabBar.subviews.first!
        firstTabbarItemImageView = firstItemView.subviews.first as? UIImageView
        firstTabbarItemImageView.contentMode = .center

        let secondItemView = self.tabBar.subviews[1]
        self.secondTabbarItemImageView = secondItemView.subviews.first as? UIImageView
        self.secondTabbarItemImageView.contentMode = .center
    }

    private func animate(_ imageView: UIImageView) {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.1, animations: {
            imageView.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1.25, y: 1.25)
        }) { _ in
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25, delay: 0.0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.5, initialSpringVelocity: 3.0, options: .curveEaseInOut, animations: {
                imageView.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1.0, y: 1.0)
            }, completion: nil)
        }
    }

    override func tabBar(_ tabBar: UITabBar, didSelect item: UITabBarItem) {
        guard let tabbarItemTag = TabbarItemTag(rawValue: item.tag) else {
            return
        }

        switch tabbarItemTag {
        case .firstViewController:
            animate(firstTabbarItemImageView)
        case .secondViewConroller:
            animate(secondTabbarItemImageView)
        }
    }
}
```

#### Second:

Set the `tag` values for the `tabBarItem` for each view controller:

First ViewController:

```
import UIKit

class FirstViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tabBarItem.tag = TabbarItemTag.firstViewController.rawValue
    }
}
```

Second ViewController:

```
import UIKit

class SecondViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tabBarItem.tag = TabbarItemTag.secondViewConroller.rawValue
    }
}
```

Make sure that everything has been setup with your storyboard (if you are using one) and that's pretty much it!

**Output:**

[image]

You could check the repo:

https://github.com/AhmadFayyas/Animated-TabbarItem/tree/master

for demonstrating the answer.

Comment: Thank you very much! your help is important. enjoy

Comment: I found an issue, when the thread 4 arrive to         firstTabbarItemImageView.contentMode = .center it crash. How can I solve please

Comment: @JackK. could you elaborate?

Comment: Ok I get it, but I've another issue: the function didSelect doesn't work, returns always item selected 0.

Comment: For Swift 4: i had to add the "tag 101" etc. manually to every tabbaritem in the storyboard, otherwise it didn't worked.

Comment: thanks its working fine for me as aspected in screenshot and upvotes you

Comment: i resolved the issue by set tag value to ever tabbaritem in storyboard

Comment: can you tell me how to add gifs to your posts on stackoverflow?

Answer (score 7):

This do the trick for me:

```
class MyCustomTabController: UITabBarController {

    override func tabBar(_ tabBar: UITabBar, didSelect item: UITabBarItem) {
        guard let barItemView = item.value(forKey: "view") as? UIView else { return }

        let timeInterval: TimeInterval = 0.3
        let propertyAnimator = UIViewPropertyAnimator(duration: timeInterval, dampingRatio: 0.5) {
            barItemView.transform = CGAffineTransform.identity.scaledBy(x: 0.9, y: 0.9)
        }
        propertyAnimator.addAnimations({ barItemView.transform = .identity }, delayFactor: CGFloat(timeInterval))
        propertyAnimator.startAnimation()
    }

}
```

Answer (score 5):

As `UITabBarItem` is not a `UIView` subclass, but an `NSObject` subclass instead, there is no direct way to animate an item when tapped.

You either have to dig up the `UIView` that belongs to the item and animate that, or create a custom tab bar.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34051646/1971013) are some ideas for digging up the `UIView`. And [here for example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30849030/1971013) how to get triggered when an item is tapped. But be very careful with this approach:

- Apple may change the `UITabBar` implementation, which could break this.
- You may interfere with iOS animations and get weird effects.

By the way, there's no need to subclass `UITabBar`. Implementing `UITabBarDelegate` is all you'd need.

I would actually advise you to just stick with the standard `UITabBar` behaviour & skinning options, and figure this out later or not at all. Things like this can burn your time without adding much to the app.

Comment: Can you link me a tutorial please?

Comment: @JackK. Tutorials most often discuss public iOS features. So, I wouldn't expect there's a tutorial. But the links I've added in my edit should get you started.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the more optimized solution with any amount of controllers.
See the comments in the code to better understand the logic.

```
class TabBarViewController: UITabBarController, UITabBarControllerDelegate {

// MARK: - UI Properties

private var firstVC = UIViewController()

private var secondVC = UIViewController()

private let thirdVC = UIViewController()
    
private var tabBarImageViews: [UIImageView] = []

public lazy var tabBarHeight =  tabBarController?.tabBar.frame.size.height

// Tag to set tabBar items and images to animate
private let startTagValue = 100

// MARK: - Lifecycle

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.delegate = self
    setControllers()
    
    // Set images to animate possibility
    let tabBarSubviews = tabBar.subviews
    var imageViewTag = startTagValue
    for subview in tabBarSubviews {
        if let imageView = subview.subviews.first as? UIImageView {
            imageView.contentMode = .center
            imageView.tag = imageViewTag
            imageViewTag += 1
            tabBarImageViews.append(imageView)
        }
    }
}

// MARK: - Methods

private func setControllers() {
    let controllers = [firstVC, secondVC, thirdVC]
    
    viewControllers = controllers.map { UINavigationController(rootViewController: $0)}
    
    // Set tag to each tabBarItem to know what imageView to animate
    var controllerItemTag = startTagValue
    controllers.forEach { controller in
        controller.tabBarItem.tag = controllerItemTag
        controllerItemTag += 1
    }
}

private func animate(_ imageView: UIImageView) {
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.1, animations: {
        imageView.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1.15, y: 1.15)
    }) { _ in
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25, delay: 0.0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.5, initialSpringVelocity: 3.0, options: .curveEaseInOut, animations: {
            imageView.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1.0, y: 1.0)
        }, completion: nil)
    }
}

// MARK: - Delegate Methods

override func tabBar(_ tabBar: UITabBar, didSelect item: UITabBarItem) {
    if let imageToAnimate = tabBarImageViews.first(where: { $0.tag == item.tag }) {
        animate(imageToAnimate)
    }
}
```

}